# Angularjs send parameters array to laravel GET route

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I just migrated to Laravel from Django.
I am not sure how to send variable number of parameters through my AJAX request from Angularjs to a GET method in Laravel.

I have a certain number of filters to a list and I only want to send those that are not undefined, along with their key, so that I can directly do this:

```
Group::where($filters)->get();
```

$filters is the array I intent to send through Angularjs, which will be something like

```
['group_id'=>101,'Country'=>'India']
```

Or whatever syntax it requires.

Also, how exactly do I specify this in my get route in route.php?

**EDIT**:

I know I can always go with the optional parameters and if else, but there has got to be a better way, isn't there?

Answer (score 1):

1). Angular $http get request.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

<p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "{! URL::to('/project/project-data') !}"
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

2). Create Controller for ajax request.

```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    class ProjectController extends BaseController {

        public function ProjectData(){

            echo "your project data placed here";
            exit()
        }
    }
```

3). Define route url in routes.php

```
Route::get('project/project-data', 'ProjectController@ProjectData');
```

Comment: @Aarohi Kulkarn  - Please let me know above answer is your solution.